# Connection with zero torsion and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, smooth-manifolds, curvature, connections

I remember encountering the following theorem many, many time ago:

> if a connection $\nabla$ has $R = 0$ and $T = 0$ then...

The problem is that I cannot remember the conclusion. Was it that the manifold must be (locally?) a Euclidean space endowed with its standard connection? It was surely something about flatness, but I can't remember the exact details (it was about connections in the tangent bundle, not in general vector bundles).

Could anyone please provide the precise statement and just a sketch of the proof? Thank you.

(I adopt the less abstract point of view where I identify a connection with its associated covariant derivative, I can visualize this approach better.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold